# NSFetchedResultsController returning objects with null attributes

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

So I'm using mogenerator with Core Data, the resultsController returns good objects with valid attributes when I first load the tableview. But when I scroll the table, all the reloaded cells are populated with objects with null attributes returned from resultsController. Is it some caching issue?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    Log *log = [self.resultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", log.text];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can't see without seeing your code, especially for cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I shouldn't put the resultsController in the viewWillLoad or viewDidLoad. I put it into it's own access method and it works fine now.